# Using 'like' statement with parameters

Tags: sql-server, database

How would I use the 'LIKE' statement in SQL with parameters? Here's what I have so far:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[select_user_by_adress]
   @user_adress nvarchar(max)
as
begin
    select * 
    from dbo.a_user_table 
    where user_adress like '%'+ @user_adress +'%'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Build dynamic SQL and then execute. Note the extra quotes needed as escape characters.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[select_user_by_adress]
   @user_adress nvarchar(max)
as
begin

declare @sql varchar(max)
@sql = 'select * from dbo.a_user_table where user_adress like ''%' + @user_adress +'%'''
execute (@sql)

end
```